# How to get pdflatex on windows to behave like linux pdflatex, on out files? Also, the grid package

Tags: pdftex

The test document in https://ctan.org/pkg/grid?lang=en works just fine in linux, but not windows. I would like to use the package in windows. pdflatex gives different outputs for windows and linux platforms. Namely, the "out" file. The grid package uses the out file in a second pass of the pdflatex, after substituting BOOKMARK for dtxmark and copying to tmp.out.

Linux:

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{About this package}{}% 1 

\BOOKMARK [2][-]{subsection.1.1}{Package options}{section.1}% 2 

\BOOKMARK [2][-]{subsection.1.2}{Package specific coding:}{section.1}% 3 

\BOOKMARK [2][-]{subsection.1.3}{Limitations of the package}{section.1}% 4 

\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{Ordinary Text}{}% 5 

\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.3}{Displayed Text}{}% 6 

\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.4}{Some bizarre text}{}% 7
```

Windows:

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{\376\377\000A\000b\000o\000u\000t\000\040\000t\000h\000i\000s\000\040\000p\000a\000c\000k\000a\000g\000e}{}%
1

\BOOKMARK [2][-]{subsection.1.1}{\376\377\000P\000a\000c\000k\000a\000g\000e\000\040\000o\000p\000t\000i\000o\000n\000s}{section.1}%
2

\BOOKMARK [2][-]{subsection.1.2}{\376\377\000P\000a\000c\000k\000a\000g\000e\000\040\000s\000p\000e\000c\000i\000f\000i\000c\000\040\000c\000o\000d\000i\000n\000g\000:}{section.1}%
3

\BOOKMARK [2][-]{subsection.1.3}{\376\377\000L\000i\000m\000i\000t\000a\000t\000i\000o\000n\000s\000\040\000o\000f\000\040\000t\000h\000e\000\040\000p\000a\000c\000k\000a\000g\000e}{section.1}%
4

\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.2}{\376\377\000O\000r\000d\000i\000n\000a\000r\000y\000\040\000T\000e\000x\000t}{}%
5

\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.3}{\376\377\000D\000i\000s\000p\000l\000a\000y\000e\000d\000\040\000T\000e\000x\000t}{}%
6

\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.4}{\376\377\000S\000o\000m\000e\000\040\000b\000i\000z\000a\000r\000r\000e\000\040\000t\000e\000x\000t}{}%
7
```

Is there a switch on Windows pdflatex's binary so that it behaves correctly wrt out files?
I know that \n is different on various OS, CRLF vs LF etc. Something else is amiss.

I would love to be able to use the grid.sty at work, but it has to be Windows here.
I really dig the "Quick Links" at the top of each page. If you can recommend another package, that would be nice too!

Comment: does it matter which encoding is used? are you sure the difference is windows/linux or simply the package versions you have not said what versions you are using

Comment: I am simply compiling the files on the CTAN site. Linux works, Windows (both miktex and texlive) do not work. UTF-16? Is there a switch in pdflatex to force to UTF-8 maybe?

Comment: I get `\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{\376\377\000A\000b\000o\000u\000t\000\040\000t\000h\000i\000s\000\040\000p\000a\000c\000k\000a\000g\000e}{}% 1` in an up to date texlive.  You did not say what versions you are using on linux. You should not have to get grid from ctan it is in texlive,  `tlmgr  info --list grid` will show the location (under texmf-dist/doc)

Comment: what do you mean by "not work" what error do you get? `{\376\377\000A\000b\00....` is not an error it is the expected format for Unicode strings.

Comment: your linux system is probably older. The windows bookmarks are fine for hyperref, but the way how rvdtx.sty recycled them will no longer work.

Comment: texlive 2023. So another alternate question is how to turn the goofy \376\377 stuff into correct characters, as in the linux version?

Wait... I I could do a substitution and replace \00 with empty string, and maybe it would be okay....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the makefile of the package contains a `if  [ -f $(file).out ] ; then cp $(file).out tmp.out; fi ;
 sed 's/BOOKMARK/dtxmark/g;' tmp.out > x.out; mv x.out tmp.out ;`. That means the documentation reuses the out-file to create small links at the top, but this fails if bookmarks are not stored as pure ascii but use unicode.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer adjust the sed a bit....

Comment: @Sam so this confirms the initial guess that the difference is unrelated to windows/linux but rather to the age of your hyperref package

Comment: @Sam you can try `\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfencoding=pdfdoc}{hyperref}` but be aware that there is no garanty that this will continue to work. At some time hyperref will probably only use unicode and no longer support pdfdoc. It would be better to correct the package.

Comment: Okay... so in the outfile, if I do a replacements: "\000" with "", "\376\377" with "", and "\040" with " ", then the file is then correct. I can then replace "BOOKMARK" with "dtxmark", save the file as tmp.out, and the compile then works!

Comment: So the question still stands. How to get pdflatex to use only pure ascii in out files, not unicode? That might help. Otherwise, I can do the substitution hack....

Comment: replacing `"\000" with ""` only works if you are writing English, basically, as any non ascii character that will mangle the input, better to do as @UlrikeFischer suggested above or `\RequirePackage[pdftex,colorlinks,unicode=false]{hyperref}` and so tell hyperref to use the old style encoding

Comment: but a better fix is ask river valley to support unicode bookmarks in their package

Comment: I changed the rvdtx.sty file with `\RequirePackage[pdftex,colorlinks,unicode=false]{hyperref}` and that works.  Thanks for the comments and help! Any recommendations for what I really want, a quick links at the top of each page in a small report? River Valley might not be in the TeX business these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is unrelated to windows/linux, but current versions of `hyperref` default to using Unicode encoding for PDF strings (the `\` escaped utf-16 based encoding your windows installation is using). Your linux installation is using the PDF-specific PDFDoc encoding (a moditified PDF specific encoding similar to Latin 1, so can only handle a limited range of Latin characters)

A real fix would be to update the `rvdtx`  package to handle the Unicode bookmarks but a temporary workaround which works at least for current hyperref releases is to force it to use the legacy encoding by adding `unicode=false` to the options passed to `hyperref` from `rvdtx.sty`